# Spring Boot with Actuator .war deployed on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, configuration, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I had configured actuator in my spring boot and basically everything works fine, till I deployed file on tomcat container.

To make actuator working I needed to created additional config class:

```
@Configuration
@Import({ EndpointAutoConfiguration.class, PublicMetricsAutoConfiguration.class,
    HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class }) public class SpringBootActuatorConfig { beans...}
```

and that's working fine - but it is not use configurations, which I have in configuration (application.properties) file eg:

management.contextPath=/server

endpoints.health.path=/ping/me

but actuator still give me endpoints without "/server" path.

I tried add:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/config/application.properties")
```

properties file is found but this not change actuator configuration.

what is a correct way to setup actuator configuration in that case?

Comment: You cannot change the contextPath when deploying a war file, the twill only work with an embedded container. Also it should just work with detecting the auto configuration, you can just not change the `contextPath`.

Comment: ok. So how can I setup conxtext path for all actuator endpoints?

Answer (score 1):

### [Spring Boot Application Properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Scroll down to the section `MANAGEMENT HTTP SERVER` where you'll find this path property:

```
management.context-path= # Management endpoint context-path. For instance `/actuator`
```

This context path affects the standard management endpoints such as /beans, /env, /health, etc.

Further down the page you'll also see the section `ACTUATOR PROPERTIES` which has configuration properties for additional Actuator Endpoints.

[Full Sample Project](https://github.com/kanderson450/stackoverflow-q38529940)

Comment: it's not working. It looks like properties from application.properties file are not loaded (for actuator)

Comment: @user1055201 Can you share a full sample project on GitHub?  I'll bet there's a problem with your configuration.

Comment: @user1055201 I've updated my answer to provide additional clarification & a full sample project.

Comment: I already have this property setup: management.context-path=/server :) Are you able to see github project?

Comment: @user1055201 Yes, but your example is convoluted.  Example projects are expected to be minimal, complete & verifiable.  See this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @user1055201 Take the sample that I shared and use that as your base.  Slowly add your customizations and once you find that the Actuator no longer works, you'll have identified the problematic config.

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem, my workaround is

```
@Bean
public EndpointHandlerMapping endpointHandlerMapping(Collection<? extends MvcEndpoint> endpoints) {
    EndpointHandlerMapping endpointHandlerMapping = new EndpointHandlerMapping(endpoints);
    endpointHandlerMapping.setPrefix("/manage");
    return endpointHandlerMapping;
}
```